# Dynamic Header Mapping in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

Can any one help on below implementation...

### Source txt/Excel File may come in below format

### Case-1

```
CName  Pan    Mobile
------------------------
A      PANA1  1234567891
B      PANB2  1234567892
```

### Case-2

```
Pan_No  Mobile_No   CustomerName  Gender
----------------------------------------
PANA1   1234567891  A             M
PANB2   1234567892  B             F
```

### Case-3

```
Email        Mobile_Number  Customer_Name  PanNumber
----------------------------------------------------
A@gmail.com  1234567891     A              PANA1
B@gmail.com  1234567892     B              PANB2
```

### Destination Table

### Customer Table

```
C_Name  C_PanNo  C_MobileNo
---------------------------
A       PANA1    1234567891
B       PANB2    1234567892
```

### ExternalHeaderMapping Table

```
Id   DestinationColumnName   ExternalHeaderName
-----------------------------------------------
1    C_Name                  CName
2    C_Name                  CustomerName
3    C_Name                  Customer_Name
3    C_PanNo                 Pan
4    C_PanNo                 Pan_No
5    C_PanNo                 PanNumber
6    C_MobileNo              Mobile
7    C_MobileNo              Mobile_No
8    C_MobileNo              Mobile_Number
```

In the above case I need to build the SSIS packge it should work for all the above three case even
the order of column is changed and new column being added.
In case-2 & Case-3 it should ignore the Gender and Email column.

I am new to SSIS, please help me how to achive the same with SSIS..I know it can only achive through Script component but
don't know how to do....

Comment: Can you post 2 3 lines of the text file, your source description need a little more clarity (for me atleast)

Comment: What kind of delimiting is it? Fixed width?

Comment: "|" Using for Text.
Actually I want Header mapping.

Comment: Is there a way to determine which format the Excel file is in other than by looking at the columns it contains? For example, does the file name or directory the file's in indicate its format?

Answer (score 0):

If I will do I will use Script Task and use below logic. (Sorry I can not write code but i can give you overall Idea).. I am not sure about performance but it works 100%...

```
Use “Script Task”

Output – c1, c2, c3 (assume output columns are fix)

Variable
@Headers = H1,H2,H3,H4 (get value from file like first row/header row)
@Columns_Object = Multiple row from Header mapping table

Row value should like: 
1)  C_Name |CName,CustomerName,Customer_Name
2)  C_PanNo |PAN,Pan_No,Pan_Number


@Array_Header = @Headers splite using “,” 
    Now value is like
        [0] = H1,
        [1] = H2, etc

Use foreach loop @Array_Header
Pick one value “H1” and find Row from @Columns_Object
    Once you get row find value before “|”  (e.g get C_Name) store in local variable @SelectCol

Switch
{
    If @SelectCol = ‘C_Name’
Then store into 
Ouput C1 =datarow.col[0] 
( “0” we get base on position of H1) if loop is looking for H2 then index is “1” 
    Else if  @SelectCol = “C_PanNo”
Ouput C2 =datarow.col[1] 
    END
}
```